# CakePHP 2.x implement edit form in ajax in a popup

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have read other posts and searched google before posting this here.

I have a jquery popup in a view where I intend to show EDIT form and then submit using ajax.

Further Details

There is a reservation controller. reservations on a particular date are shown in the index ctp in a table . When user clicks on edit button a div pops up. Now I need to show Edit form and submit it via Ajax.

Please can somebody point me in the right direction , may be some help or some tutorial.

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the standard CakePHP edit method?

If so, one option would be to create an element for the edit function. In Views/Reservations, if your view is edit.ctp, your view in Views/Elements would also be edit.ctp. OR, you could create a new method in your controller, create a new view in Views/Reservations, and a new view in Views/Elements.

Then, in your pop-up, you should be able to call the element, edit the form, and submit.